# Joe's Blogs .Net API

Tags: .net, xml-rpc, joeblogs

I am using JoeBlogs API for XMLRPC.  Everytime I try to get a page by the ID it throw this error:

XmlRpcPage[] : element 0 : struct mapped to type XmlRpcPage : member wp_author_id mapped to type Int32

From this code.

```
        /// <summary>
    /// Get the page identified by the page id. 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="pageid"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public Page GetPage(string pageid)
    {
        var page = _wrapper.GetPage(this.BlogID, pageid, Username, Password);
        return Map.To.Page(page);
    }
```

Anybody know how to get this to work?  I can use the "getPost()" method but when I go to update the Page it blows up.

Answer (score 0):

Get the lastest it has a fix.
https://github.com/alexjamesbrown/JoeBlogs